# Row limit increase

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I need to view 100,000 rows in LibreOffice Calc, but row size is limited.

How can I increase row size, or any tool to view all 100,000 lines?

I want to do data mining with these records. The file contain 100,000 customer records. Single file in CSV format. 100,000 rows and 40 columns I need to view. I'm using LibreOffice version 3.

Comment: What the Hell is "one Lakh"? Hound multiplied by chicken?

Comment: @ChristianSauer it's 100,000 - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Comment: I guessed that it is a number . but the author could have translated it for us...

Comment: @ChristianSauer it's a number that is only used in India. I have edited the question for you.

Answer (score 2):

The row limit of Libre Office [depends on the version](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/8631/upper-limit-to-number-of-rows-in-calc/) you are using:

- pre 3.3.3: limit is 65 536 rows
- 3.3.3 and later: 1 048 576 rows (1M)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I need round about 9*10^6 rows in LibreOffice Calc.

My workaround would be:

1. open csv with pandas in jupyter notebook
2. slice to my needs (<=2^20 rows)
3. save sliced dataframe as csv-segment
4. open csv-segment with Calc

It's a shame that there is not an option like a slider to max out the possible row count. 10M rows with 1024 colums with 32 bit numbers should just circa need 4byte * 1024 * 10*2^20 =(around) 40 GiByte RAM.

Maybe we get this option hopefully later.